# How to WriteFile to a PhysicalDrive (Windows 7) without getting ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, windows-7

I'm trying to write a test pattern to every sector of a formatted USB drive. There is one logical drive (e.g. h:). This volume is FAT-formatted and contains data to be overwritten. Also, I want to overwrite the whole physical drive. The program is running with elevated user rights.

First I did the following:

```
// from the drive letter "h:" I get the physical disk number using
// IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS => "\\.\PhysicalDrive2"

hDevice = ::CreateFile( "\\.\PhysicalDrive2", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
  FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL ); 

// get the number of available sectors with IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX
// => ulNumberOfSectors

// now I try to write some sectors, e.g. 2 (I want to use a higher value):
WriteFile( hDevice, abBuffer, 2*512, &byteswritten, NULL );
```

The call to `WriteFile` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

If I write one sector, it works.

When I overwrite the first sector and plug the device out and in again, Windows wants to format it. In this situation my code with 2048 sectors at once works without `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I also unmounted the volume as described in [CodeProject: WriteFile on Physical Drives with Windows 7](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/97356/WriteFile-on-Physical-Drives-with-Windows-7/?cmt=7750#answer2) but this didn't change anything. Obviously the volume is unmounted because it's no longer visible in Windows Explorer.

I want to write more than a single sector due to perfomance reasons. I'm also afraid that other problems in the field might occur because I don't fully understand ths problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And you are running as administrator?

Comment: @David: Yes, I'm running elevated.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have problems with different `WriteFile()` sizes, but I did solve the

> WriteFile(): Access is denied `<ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED/5>` to
>   '\.\physicaldriveX

devices (usually USB HDD/SSD) in Windows 7 running as Administrator (elevated rights) as follows:

Computer Management -> Disk Management:

- Volume (H: in your case) -> right-click -> Delete Volume
- Disk (Disk 2 in your case) -> right-click -> Off-line
- Disk (Disk 2 in your case) -> right-click -> On-line

After that, I'm able to write to '\.\physicaldriveX' with no problem.

I think the Win7 locks (unlike previous Windows releases) the physical device as long as there is any file system on the device to avoid consistency problems.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access sectors of a drive which are owned by a mounted filesystem.

See [Changes to the file system and to the storage stack to restrict direct disk access and direct volume access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448)

The documentation for [`FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364562.aspx) describes the following sequence for overwriting a filesystem:

1. Open a volume.
2. Lock the volume.
3. Format the volume.
4. Dismount the volume.
5. Unlock the volume.
6. Close the volume handle.

Your pattern-writing operation would be in step 3 instead of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `clean` to **delete all the partitions (and ALL DATA)** on the disk:

```
C:\> diskpart
Diskpart> list disk

Diskpart> select disk N (where N is your disk number)

Diskpart> clean

Diskpart> exit
```

Comment: You should preface your post with a warning of what this does. An inexperienced user doing this could easily wipe the data from a drive without knowing the full ramifications of this command.