# WriteFile to SD card (physical hard disk) fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, writefile

I'm trying to write to physical Hard Disk (SD Card/*FAT32*) directly using Windows API: *WriteFile()* but it always fails with **ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5)**. I've tried many options suggested by some other posts such as *unmount/lock* but nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone have a better idea what is the root cause of this and how can we access to the physical drive directly from Windows API?

This is the sample code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

DWORD lastError;

int main (void) {
  uint16_t x, y;
  uint8_t  buffer[512];
  DWORD    bytesWritten, status;

  HANDLE sdCardHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2", GENERIC_READ    | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                                            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  if(sdCardHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
    return -1;
  }
  
  for (y = 1; y < 10001; y++) { 
    memset(buffer, y, sizeof(buffer));
    if (WriteFile(sdCardHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesWritten, NULL) == 0) {
      lastError = GetLastError();
      printf("WriteFile error: 0x%X\n", lastError);
      CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
      return -2;
    }
    printf("%d\n", y);
  }

  CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running your process elevated (with admin privileges)?

Comment: I did try running .exe of this code with admin but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608466/how-to-writefile-to-a-physicaldrive-windows-7-without-getting-error-access-den, or this: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/245762/WriteFile-to-physicaldrive-on-Win7

Comment: I doubt that `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` is valid when requesting access to the physical drive.

Comment: Try `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME`, `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`. It should work without `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, but who knows. Also buffer should be aligned on 512 or 4096 byte boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for the comments.

So I figured out a way to work around this problem (in Windows 10). The *workaround* is to ***lock, dismount and create disk as GPT*** to make Windows think it's unallocated disk. For whatever reason if it was formatted as FAT/FAT32, I just wouldn't be able to WriteFile to the card.

The following is the example code that is working for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

static CREATE_DISK   raw; // dummy raw to create disk as GPT to trick Windows to see it as unallocated
static DWORD         lastError;
static HANDLE        sd_handle;

int main (void) {
  uint16_t x, y;
  uint8_t  i, buffer[512];
  DWORD    bytes;

  if ((sd_handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2", 
                              GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                              FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                              NULL, 
                              OPEN_EXISTING, 
                              FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                              NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Error 0x%X openning Physical Drive\n", GetLastError());  
    return -1;
  }

  // Workaround to lock, dismount, and create disk as GPT to trick Windows to see drive as unallocated
  if (!DeviceIoControl(sd_handle, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &bytes, NULL)) {
    puts("Error: Cannot lock volume");
    CloseHandle(sd_handle);
    return -2;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl(sd_handle, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME , NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &bytes, NULL)) {
    puts("Error: Cannot dismount volume");
    CloseHandle(sd_handle);
    return -3;
  }

  raw.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_GPT;
  if (!DeviceIoControl(sd_handle, IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK, &raw, sizeof(raw), NULL, 0, &bytes, NULL)) {
    puts("Error: Cannot create disk");
    CloseHandle(sd_handle);
    return -4;
  }

  // unlock, close, and reopen again to allow Windows to see it as newly unallocated drive
  if (!DeviceIoControl(sd_handle, FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &bytes, NULL)) {
    puts("Error: Cannot unlock volume");
    CloseHandle(sd_handle);
    return -5;
  }

  CloseHandle(sd_handle);

  if ((sd_handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2", 
                              GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                              FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                              NULL, 
                              OPEN_EXISTING, 
                              FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                              NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Error 0x%X openning Physical Drive\n", GetLastError());  
    return -6;
  }


  // Note for WriteFile:
  // The GetLastError code ERROR_IO_PENDING is not a failure; 
  // it designates the write operation is pending completion asynchronously.
  for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    memset(buffer, i, sizeof(buffer));
    if (!WriteFile(sd_handle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytes, NULL)
     &&((lastError = GetLastError()) != ERROR_IO_PENDING)) {
      printf("WriteFile error: 0x%X\n", lastError);
      CloseHandle(sd_handle);
      return -7;
    }
  }
}
```

Again, this is just a workaround that I found out to be working for me, but I don't know what was the exact cause yet. If anyone knows the root cause and is willing to share that would be great.