How to get write access to device?
When I write to a disk device or a drive, sometimes I get an access denied error:
HANDLE hd=CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1",GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
//HANDLE hd=CreateFile("\\\\.\\C:",GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
WriteFile(hd,...);

The error persists even after I dismount the volume:
HANDLE hd=CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1",GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
//HANDLE hd=CreateFile("\\\\.\\C:",GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
DeviceIoControl(hd,FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
WriteFile(hd,...);

I encountered this problem in Windows Disk Management when I tried to format a volume or delete a volume. Disk Management will show a dialog saying some process is accessing that volume and if I want to proceed. If I choose yes, the formatting or deletion can be performed without problem. I want to know how I can achieve the same in code, i.e., what API I should use to gain the write access.

Under Physical Disks and Volumes you'll find: "The caller must have administrative privileges."

@IInspectable Yes, I run the program as administrator.

According to WriteFile, the sectors you want to write fall within a mounted volume, but you don't have successfully locked or dismounted the volume. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608466/how-to-writefile-to-a-physicaldrive-windows-7-without-getting-error-access-den.
